# docker inside docker on windows

Tags: windows, docker

run jenkins with docker on windows, but how to run docker command in windows docker container?
in linux:

```
docker run -it --rm --privileged --name dockerindocker -v //var/run/docker.sock:/var/run/docker.sock docker
```

Are there any similar commands available for docker in Windows 10?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It [looks like](https://github.com/docker-library/docker/issues/49) there's no Windows support for it.

> That would require some sort of support from Windows and is not something that they are working on.